# php mail sends multiple copies

Tags: php, copy, email

i'm using drupal 6 and tries to send an email to all users by using following code . The problem is sometimes the mail sends to users **multiple times** but sent folder holds 1 entry for each user. Specially *yahoo ids got more than 2 mails*(3 to 4) and sent shows 2 emails sent to each yahoo id . is anyone knows it ..

```
<?php
 require("/var/www/drupal/sites/all/modules/smtp/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");
 $con = mysql_connect("***","***","*****");
 $select_db=mysql_select_db("drupaldb", $con);
 $result = mysql_query("select uid,name,mail,data from users ");
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
   mailit($row['name'],$row['mail']);
   flush();
   sleep(3);
 }
 print "<br>*******************************************<br>";
 function mailit($name,$rec)
 {
   $content="<div> Test mail </div>";

   $mail = new PHPMailer();
   $mail->IsSMTP(); 
   $mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com"; 
   $mail->Port = 465; 
   $mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
   $mail->Username = "**********"; 
   $mail->Password = "*********";
   $mail->From = "*********";
   $mail->FromName = "****";
   $mail->AddAddress($rec,$name);
   $mail->Subject = "Test mail";
   $mail->IsHTML(true);
   $mail->Body = $content;
   $mail->AltBody ='Test Mail'; 
   if(!$mail->Send())
   {
     error_log("Mass Mail: ".$mail->ErrorInfo, 0);
     echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo."<br>";
   }
   else
   {
     echo "Message has been sent to <b>".$name."</b> through <i>".$rec."</i><br>";
   }
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems fine. Are you sure that different users don't share some email addresses? The `mail` column should be normalized and `UNIQUE`. Also, is the script being executed multiple times?